# Which version of ECMA specification introduced hoisting?

Tags: javascript, hoisting

Does anyone know when the specifications for hoisting was introduced?  And whether internet explorer version 6 supported it?

I didn't realize hoisting existed because these days, all my JavaScript code is transpiled.

I vaguely remember feeling proud on my first job as a web developer when I explained to my boss that his JavaScript program was crashing in IE6 or IE7 because he was invoking a function that was declared much later.  I wonder if I have gone crazy and remembered things wrong?

Comment: I'm pretty sure hoisting worked in IE6 although I might be going crazy, too. I also tried to forget as much as I could about writing code for IE < 8, so I might have actually succeeded with that.

Comment: You might be rememering it slightly wrong, though - it might not have been a function declaration but a variable with a function expression, e.g., `fn(); var fn = function() {};`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that JavaScript has implemented hoisting from the beginning. According to the [MDN article on hoisting](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Hoisting):

> Hoisting is a term you will not find used in any normative specification prose prior to ECMAScript® 2015 Language Specification.

I read this to say that ECMA 2015 is the first time the term was used in the language spec but that the concept existed prior to that.